# Get Date From Database to DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I am trying to get the date from the database and show it to a datetimepicker.

This is what I have tried:

```
public void LoadIssuedDate()
{
    dtIssuedDate.CustomFormat = "";
    cn.Open();
    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT IssuedDate FROM Transactions", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dtIssuedDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);
}
```

But an error occurred that says:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Any help would so much be appreciated.

Comment: what is the datatype of `IssuedDate`

Comment: What is the `string` result? Have you printed it to the console?

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla the datatype is nvarchar, the database we use is given by our teacher

Comment: What is your dateformat?

Comment: Did your teacher define the data type of `IssuedDate` as `nvarchar` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: @Jimi yes, he defined it as nvarchar

Comment: @heejin, can you update your post by providing some sample data of `IssuedDate`

Comment: Your teacher should read this - [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datatype of `IssuedDate` is `varchar/nvarchar` then, you should try `DateTime.ParseExact` by specifying the format. something like below -

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(),"M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Also by looking at your query, I suggest you to try `ExecuteScalar`
>
> And If the column intention is to store Date, then change the datatype to `DateTime`

Comment: @heejin, what is the dateformat you are using to store in database?

Comment: the dateformat M/dd/yyyy, and yes i will change the datatype to DateTime. Thank you so much

Comment: @heejin, have updated the post with the dateformat. Yes, it is good if you change to DateTime.